# Angular 5 - Update my model with string replace on input change

Tags: angular, event-handling

My requirement is as below,

I have a text field, which should accept only numbers.
When I enter any other characters, it should not be allowed (that is it should not be displayed in the text box).
I cannot use **input type number** as it allows **"-"**, **"+"** and **e**.

I tried using many events like, **ngModelChange**, **keypress**, **keydown**, **input**, **change**.
But none of them worked as expected.

I have recreated my problem in below link,

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-en6w18

Any help appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Why **keydown** didn't work?

Comment: When i use keydown, the last character i type is still displayed and not removed. I have no idea why that happens. You can check the behaviour in the link I have shared.

Comment: check this, it works
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tkaeug

Comment: Thanks, It works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call preventDefault if the entered char is not a number

here is how it will work:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tkaeug

Note: don't forget to allow alt, ctrl, command, backspace.... etc.